# Running multiple functions at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, time

This must be a question asked a lot, and yet I couldn't quite find what I'm looking for.

Imagine this:

- A program starts up "Hello, what's your name?"
- You enter a number and it goes "Your name can't be a number!"

You keep entering a number and keep getting that error, while in the background it just keeps track of how long the program has been running, by doing n++ every second, no matter what goes on in the text/input part. Eventually you could enter something like "time" and then it shows how long you've been there, in seconds...

SO my question is: Just how the hell would you go about doing that? To have them run independently?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm not trying to do this timing thing in particular, it's just the easiest example I could come up with to ask about running functions independently..

Comment: Read about timers and in general about multi-threading.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just check time at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: what if i enter the correct name the first time?

Comment: What you are looking for is called concurrency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to run parallel tasks in order to measure the elapsed time. An example in C++11:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    // Or whatever you want to do...

    auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsedMS =
        (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1)).count()

    std::cout << elapsedMS;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since it seems you are interested in a way to launch several tasks in parallel, here is a hint (again, using C++11):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int long_computation(int x, int y)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    return (x + y);
}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, long_computation, 42, 1729);

    // Do things in the meanwhile...
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    // And we could continue...

    std::cout << f.get(); // Here we join with the asynchronous operation
}
```

The example above starts a long computation that will take at least 5 seconds, and *in the meanwhile* does other stuff. Then, eventually, it calls `get()` on the future object to join with the asynchronous computation and retrieve its result (waiting until it is finished if it hasn't finished yet).

Comment: andy you could show the code inside the "error loop" where he could check if "time" has been entered and then display current elapsed time accordingly.

Comment: @Koushik See the OP's edit, he's not specifically interested in the example. He's asking about multithreading.

Comment: @JBentley oops missed it.sorry

Comment: @JBentley: Indeed, I realized that only after the OP's edit. I edited the answer.

Comment: Well, I hate to say this, but I only started learning C++ about a month ago. I was learning Java before that, and, well... C++ is pretty complicated compared to Java.. Maybe I should just go back

Comment: @Adam: Well, the above examples take less than 10 lines of code each... I am not a Java expert, so I can't make a comparison, but the above does not seem too bad to me

Comment: @Adam - what is so complicated about the examples above? C++ is undoubtedly the "harder" but also the more capable, performing and efficient language. You could be a perfectly proficient C++ programmer with 1/5 of the language, and still ask for help if you need something more advanced.

Comment: @Adam, even though C++ is definitely harder than other programming languages, it is definitely still worth learning!  Take the time to study it and you will definitely find that it is a lot more capable of high-end graphics, incredible efficiency, and uncompromising speed than many other programming languages.  I'm pretty new to C++ too, but I can definitely say that it was one of the best decisions I've ever made to start learning it.  Give it a chance and you will be rewarded!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use threads, not just counting time you can use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html).

**Example:**

```
include <boost/thread.hpp>

void task1() { 
    // do something
}

void task2() { 
    // do something
}

void main () {
    using namespace boost; 
    thread thread1 = thread(task1);
    thread thread2 = thread(task2);
    thread2.join();
    thread1.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not trying to do this timing thing in particular, it's just the easiest example I could come up with to ask about running functions independently..

Then you may want to look into multithreading. In C++11, you can do this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void func1() {
    std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;
}

void func2() {
    std::cout << "func2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread td1(func1);
    std::thread td2(func2);
    std::cout << "Started 2 threads. Waiting for them to finish..." << std::endl;
    td1.join();
    td2.join();
    std::cout << "Threads finished." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you're not using C++11, you still have options. You can look into:

- [Boost Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html) (Requires Boost of course)
- [POSIX threads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I now just have one question;
What does the .join() function do?

Comment: It waits for a thread to finish and returns to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to increment your own time variable.  Just record the time when the program starts and the `time` command will return the difference between time now and start time.

More generally -

1. It's possible to kick off a long-running task in another thread.  You'll need to research this on your own; try googling that phrase.
2. Event-driven programming might be more appropriate for this use case.  Try "C++ event driven IO" for google, or something.